# Minimum hardware requirements for running 8 thin clients with LTSP and LAMP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thin-client, hardware, ltsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I wanted to figure out what are the minimum hardware requirements for running 8 smooth thin clients with Ubuntu and LTSP. The thin clients need to be able to run a web browser to access a webapp (apache, mysql and django) hosted locally in the same server.

How much RAM do i need? cpu?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You need more than an Amiga and less than the IBM Sequoia (fastest supercomputer in the world at current).  And yes, that's really about all we can say.  Do some benchmarks, run some tests and figure out your hardware requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You do that through testing. And be forewarned, the new versions of the browsers chew up a lot of RAM.

I've been deploying Ubuntu 9.10 servers for a few years and 8G RAM was fine for those for 10 users running Tbird 2, Firefox 3.x, and OpenOffice. 4G won't even reliably run those apps for 2 people without swapping now.